# C++ create string of text and variables

Tags: c++, string, variables, std

I'm trying to do something very simple and yet, after an hour of so of searching a I can't find a suitable answer so I must be missing something fairly obvious.

I'm trying to dynamically create filenames for use with ifstream. Whilst I understand various methods are available of doing this, I have settled on creating a std::string, and the using stringname.c_str to convert to const.

The problem is however that I need to create the string with a mix of variables and predefined text values. I'm getting compiler errors, so this must be a syntax issue.

Pseudo

```
std::string var = "sometext" + somevar + "sometext" + somevar;
```

Thanks!

Comment: if it's a syntax error you should post the actual code then we can tell you want the syntax error is (and why it's wrong) and you'll learn more than if we just give you the correct syntax.

Comment: `std::string var = std::string("sometext") + somevar + "sometext" + somevar;`

Comment: as [@yury's solution shows you can also use printf style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20630764/52074) API with `boost::format`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Have you considered using stringstreams?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "sometext" << somevar << "sometext" << somevar;
std::string var = oss.str();
```

Comment: Exactly + std::ostringstream would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @eli - This was the method which I had initially attempted without any luck, but is now working! Can you explain what ss.str() is doing at all?

Comment: `ss.str()` is extracting the contents of the `stringstream`.

Answer (score 48):

In C++11 you can use [std::to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/):

```
std::string var = "sometext" + std::to_string(somevar) + "sometext" + std::to_string(somevar);
```

Answer (score 36):

```
std::string var = "sometext" + somevar + "sometext" + somevar;
```

This doesn't work because the additions are performed left-to-right and `"sometext"` (the first one) is just a `const char *`. It has no `operator+` to call. The simplest fix is this:

```
std::string var = std::string("sometext") + somevar + "sometext" + somevar;
```

Now, the first parameter in the left-to-right list of `+` operations is a `std::string`, which has an `operator+(const char *)`. That operator produces a string, which makes the rest of the chain work.

You can also make all the operations be on `var`, which is a `std::string` and so has all the necessary operators:

```
var = "sometext";
var += somevar;
var += "sometext";
var += somevar;
```

Comment: ...assuming that *type* of `somevar` is on the `operator +(*type*)` list.

Comment: @doc Yep. Otherwise, you'll have to add some code around `somevar` to make it work. For example, if it's an `int`, you can use Boost::lexical_cast to make it a string. (Or, in that case, the `stringstream` solution might be better.)

Answer (score 15):

The new way to do with c++20 is using [format](http://eel.is/c++draft/format).

```
#include <format>

auto var = std::format("sometext {} sometext {}", somevar, somevar);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use sprintf:

```
char str[1024];
sprintf(str, "somtext %s sometext %s", somevar, somevar);
```

Comment: This isn't very safe though. The additional complexity of making it safe probably makes it not a very good choice.

Comment: `snprintf()` would be a better choice. `snprintf(str, 1024, "somtext %s sometext %s", somevar, somevar);`

Comment: This isn't safe, but *too* handy in comparision with bulky std::string & ostringstream.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Why is it not safe? Do you mean that it is prone to cyberattacks? If yes, how so? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @ViníciusQueiroz What if the formatted output exceeds 1023 characters and overflows `str`?

Comment: Oh, now I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

See also [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html):

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

std::string var = (boost::format("somtext %s sometext %s") % somevar % somevar).str();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like:

```cpp
#define Compose(...) ComposeFn({ __VA_ARGS__ })

std::string ComposeFn(std::initializer_list<std::string> strList) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    for(std::string str : strList) {
        ss << str;
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

And then use it like:

```cpp
int errcode = 404;
std::cout << Compose("[ERROR]: (", errcode, ") doesn't exist") << std::endl;
```

The `Compose` macro is just to avoid using the curly brackets. You could also use a variadic function, but eh

Answer (score 0):

Since c++14 you can use the std::string operator""s from std::string_literals

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::string var = "sometext"s + somevar + "sometext"s + somevar;
```

The compiler will add a std::string in place of the literal, and as such you can use the "+" operator with it.