# Appendheader needs to append string, variable and then string again

Tags: json, curl, http-headers

Hopefully this is an easy one for someone out there. I need to append a long command that has strings and variables in it.

```
this->AppendHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + offset "-" + (offset + part_size - 1) "/" + file_size);
```

This is not acceptable in C++. How can I format the above so the Header looks like

```
Content-Range: bytes 0-19/40
```

(just a fyi - offset is 0, part_size is 20 and file_size is 40)

Comment: I am not a C++ developer but is what you are looking for String interpolation? like this? [stackoverflow.com/questions/10219225](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219225/c-create-string-of-text-and-variables/25895736)

Comment: @Landy Thanks! I think it was the "/" it didnt like. I used single quotes and it seemed to compile.