# How to throw an error message with an argument?

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception, throw

I'm really struggling with throwing an error message that includes an argument from the function. I know I can do:

```
throw std::out_of_range("Empty tree");
```

What I am struggling with is another error I am supposed to throw, which is:

```
"Cannot find ceil for key <key>"
```

As you can see, I am supposed to include the key for which I cannot find the ceil for. I have the key as a variable in the function from which I am throwing the exception, but I have no idea how to include it in what will eventually be printed by e.what().

EDIT: This is a template function as a member of a class, so key is just type T right now. Hence why I think formatting it as a c string wasn't working.

Comment: What is the type of `key`?

Comment: Use `std::string` to create the message.

Comment: You'll need some sort of `stringify` function that converts whatever `T` is to a `std::string`.  Then you can use it like `throw std::out_of_range("Cannot find ceil for key " + stringify(key));`

Comment: Youll need to be more specific about what the `key` object is. Please post the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard exceptions only take a string as an argument:

e.g. **out_of_range**, see [apache.org docs](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/out-of-range.html)

```
namespace std {
  class out_of_range : public logic_error {
  public:
    explicit out_of_range(const string&  what_arg);
  };
}
```

You could use any method to build the string beforehand, and then pass that as the parameter to the exception.

**Example**:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Cannot find ceil for key " << key;
std::string errorString = oss.str();

throw std::out_of_range(errorString);
```

For other ways to create the string, see [C++ create string of text and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219225/c-create-string-of-text-and-variables#10219267)